# Binding ListCollectionView containing dynamic objects does not show columns in grid WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm, radgridview, listcollectionview

I'm using telerik `RadGridView` with a view model which derives from `DynamicObject`.

When this view model is bound to the grid via an `ObservableCollection<T>` all columns are displayed as expected, but when the observable collection is used as the source for a ListCollectionView and this is then bound to the grid then NO columns are displayed.

How do I get ListCollectionView to work with dynamic objects and grid controls?

An example is shown below, when I bind 'AllItems' then columns 'Value1' & 'Value2' are displayed but when I bind FilteredItems there are no columns displayed.

```
public abstract class BaseViewModel<T> : DynamicObject
{

}

public class MyItemViewModel : BaseViewModel<MyItem>
{
    private MyItem _myItem;

    public MyItemViewModel(int i)
    {
        _myItem = new MyItem();
        _myItem.Value1 = "Ollie " + i;
        _myItem.Value2 = 42 + i;
    }

    public override IEnumerable<string> GetDynamicMemberNames()
    {
        return new[] {"Value1", "Value2"};
    }

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        if (binder.Name == "Value1")
        {
            result = _myItem.Value1;
            return true;
        }
        else if (binder.Name == "Value2")
        {
            result = _myItem.Value2;
            return true;
        }

        return base.TryGetMember(binder, out result);
    }

    public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
    {
        if (binder.Name == "Value1")
        {
            _myItem.Value1 = (string)value;
            return true;
        }
        else if (binder.Name == "Value2")
        {
            _myItem.Value2 = (int)value;
            return true;
        }

        return base.TrySetMember(binder, value);
    }
}


public class TestHarness
{
    private readonly ObservableCollection<MyItemViewModel> _items = null; 
    private readonly ICollectionView _filteredItems = null;

    public TestHarness()
    {
        _items = new ObservableCollection<MyItemViewModel>();
        _filteredItems = new MyListCollectionView(_items);

        _items.Add(new MyItemViewModel(1));
        _items.Add(new MyItemViewModel(2));
        _items.Add(new MyItemViewModel(3));
    }

    public IEnumerable<MyItemViewModel> AllItems { get { return _items; } }

    public IEnumerable FilteredItems { get { return _filteredItems; } } 
}
```

Comment: after adding to _items is FilteredItems's getter called ?

Comment: yes it is, I can see the correct number of rows being created in the grid but not the columns.

Comment: AutoGenerateColumns is not set to false right ?

Comment: I'm guessing the ColumnHeaderPresenter doesn't consider dynamic objects i don't know how they appear in reflection , why don't you I would create some behavior or any attached context which listens to ItemsSourceChanged event , there you should create and bind the column's in code.

Comment: AutoGenerateColumns is set to true...